# UI Idea For Android Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

Here is the image/snapshot of present UI  but top headers (Select Discipline,Select Location)are getting so many spaces in screen and my whole required screen is getting short So whats the alternative of design this screen using Android.This screen contents are generated dynamically from Web Service.

Whats the way to remove top buttons and where should i need to place top buttons functionality so that after removal of button my contents will be more prominent?

[image: UI SCREEN SHORT]

Answer (score 0):

Make the UI Top header a combo box